# How do you update to Python 3.11 in the base environment of Anaconda? Or at least create a new environment with all the base packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, anaconda3, python-3.11

I am using the latest Anaconda Navigator (for Python 3.9), and I know how to make a new environment with Python 3.11 in Anaconda. However, whenever I create a new environment, there are hardly any packages there. The base has all the packages I need and when I try a new environment with Python 11, I always run into silly problems like basic packages such as pandas not being there.

To update python to 3.11 in the base environment, I have tried everything I could find online. I went into the environment in Anaconda, typed in Python and clicked "mark for specific version update" for 3.11, and when I did I was met with the infamous "The following packages will be modified" box and it was blank for a long time. I also tried Choco and that did not work. I also tried some stuff in command line but to no avail.

Essentially what I want is to either update the base to 3.11 or have a new environment where there's all the base packages and 3.11. If only the point and click updating in Anaconda worked!

Comment: I came across the same issue and in the end gave up on Anaconda. I installed Python 3.11 and Jupyter directly and then all the packages I actually use using PIP. Works without problems and easy to keep up to date with PIP.

Comment: @user19077881 you could have just used `pip` with your anaconda installation.

Comment: So, the best way is to keep track of individual `environment.yml` files specifying each environment. If you are just dumping everything into the base environment (which sort of defeats the purpose of using virtual environments) you can always export a specification using `conda env export --no-builds > environment.yml`, this will be messier than a hand kept file, but you can use it to create a new environment with the same dependencies.

Comment: you can try to add the `--from-history` tag to `conda env export` as well, as this just puts the libraries that you "specifically asked for", which will be less messy. So all in all, `conda env export --from-history --no-builds > environment.yml`

Answer (score 9):

Conda allows you to install a new version of python within or for a given environment. For example, to update Python to 3.11 (or any other version) in the current environment do:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge python=3.11
```

To update python for another environment just do:

```bash
conda install -n _env-name_-c conda-forge python=3.11
```

Notes:

- `-c conda-forge` is optional.
- you can verify the version of python installed by `python --version`
- upgrading the python distribution will trigger updates/downgrades of several packages, review the update plan carefully.
- beware of compatibility issues.

Comment: Users should not replace Anaconda **base** Python with Conda Forge versions. Conda Forge does not support this and users are on their own if they do so (expect DLL incompatibilities). Further, changing Python versions in place is discouraged by Conda. It is almost always is more efficient to create a new environment with the desired Python version specified.

Answer (score 4):

At the time of OP (23 January 2023), Anaconda was not yet building for Python 3.11 (see the [Anaconda Cloud builds of `anaconda`](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda/files)). Now that it is, one could create a new environment with

```bash
conda create -n anaconda_py311 python=3.11 anaconda
```

However, Conda Forge had mostly completed its Python 3.11 migration of packages, so pretty much everything one would want was available through that. That is, one cannot use the `anaconda` package, but instead must explicitly specify the packages one requires, such as

```bash
conda create -n py311 -c conda-forge python=3.11 scikit-learn pandas scipy
```

including whatever additional packages are desired.

Comment: @Soumendra thanks; updated answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install -c conda-forge python=3.11
```

worked for me

```
conda install -c conda-forge python=3.12
```

to install version 3.12 which is the latest as of now